# Cannot require electron-store

Tags: angular, electron

I want to use electron-store with angular but when i try to require it, i got some errors. I'm using angular v12 and electorn v8.

In my code:

```
var Store = require("electron-store");

var store = new Store();
```

Results:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
    at getElectronPath (index.js:8)
    at Object.46897 (index.js:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.32256 (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.34758 (ap.service.ts:12)
```

I tried a lot of thing found in internet but I cannot resolv it.